# np.repeat on two 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What I'm looking for is how to apply a dyadic function on non-1D arrays. For instance, let's say I have a dyadic function `f` and two arrays `x` & `y`.

More specifically, let's assume

`f` is `np.repeat`

`x = np.array(['O'])`

`y = np.array(5)`

Then, `f(x,y)` in this case would be `np.repeat(x,y)` which would returns `array(['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'])`

Now, let `x = np.array(['O','T])` then

f(x,y) `np.repeat(x,y)` would return `array(['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T'])`

And if `y = np.array([2,5])`,

`np.repeat(x,y)` would return `array(['O', 'O', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T']`

Now, x1 is repeated y1 times, and x2 is repeated y2 times.

Similarly, if the shapes of `x` and `y` are the same, then f(x,y) `np.repeat(x,y)` should not raise any error for the higher dimension arrays.

However, if `x` and `y` have (10,2) shape like below, it raises `ValueError: object too deep for desired array`

```
y = np.random.randint(5, size = (10,2)) 
y
array([[4, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 0],
       [3, 4],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [3, 0],
       [1, 0]])

x = np.repeat(np.array(['O','T'])[np.newaxis,:], 10, axis=0)
x    
array([['O', 'T'],
       ['O', 'T'],
       ['O', 'T'],
       ['O', 'T'],
       ['O', 'T'],
       ['O', 'T'],
       ['O', 'T'],
       ['O', 'T'],
       ['O', 'T'],
       ['O', 'T']], dtype='<U1') 


np.repeat(x,y)

     56 
     57     try:
---> 58         return bound(*args, **kwds)
     59     except TypeError:
     60         # A TypeError occurs if the object does have such a method in its

ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

Why is this happening? f(x,y) with the same dimension raises an error. Is there anything that I'm missing here?

Can anyone explain this problem? Thanks in advance!

ps. plz no for loop and list comprehension. = ]

Comment: Without axis parameter, `repeat` flattens `x`, and returns a flat result.  See the docs.  You have one case using `axis`.  But as pointed out in your previous question, `repeat` cannot produce a ragged output.  It can repeat the columns of `x` or the rows of `x`, but it can't do something different for each row.

Comment: The docs show what it can do with a 2d `x` array - expanding rows, columns or the flattened.  It does not show any sort of ragged array!

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you so much for your help! I wanted a little more broad explanation about applying functions, but I believe this would be sufficient for this np.repeat case. Thank you again!

Comment: In a sense every function has its own rules about parameters, though there are various categories (e.g. `ufunc`, `np.sum` etc).  `np.repeat` is one of a kind (`np.tile` is python code built on `repeat`). But if there is a `axis` parameter, omitting it usually means operate on flattened arrays.